# How to update an entity with a collection of abstract types by using GraphDiff?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, graphdiff

I have some models:

```
public class RootEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public virtual ICollection<AbstractEntity> CollectionA {get; set;}
}

public abstract class AbstractEntity
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
}

public class DerivedEntityA : AbstractEntity
{
    public virtual ICollection<AnotherType> CollectionB {get; set;} 
}

public class DerivedEntityB : AbstractEntity
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

The relationships of above models are like this:

```
 RootEntity ---> ICollection<AbstractEntity>
                                 ┗━━ DerivedEntityA ---> ICollection<AnotherType>
                                 ┗━━ DerivedEntityB
 --->    has a
┗━━  derived from
```

Now I want to update a `RootEntity` entity named `rootEntity` by using GraphDiff:

```
 context.UpdateGraph(rootEntity, map => map
             .OwnedCollection(r => r.CollectionA, with => with
                 .OwnedCollection(de => de.CollectionB)  // this doesn't work because 'de' doesn't have 'CollectionB'
                 )
     );
```

So how can I update it properly?

Comment: Caveat: I've never used GraphDiff and I don't know how it works, but I found your question curious. I had a few ideas/comments. Is CollectionA guaranteed to only have entities of type DerivedEntityA? If not, I suspect GraphDiff might not be able to deal with that. If it does, could you do something like `.OwnedCollection<RootEntity,DerivedEntityA>(r => r.CollectionA.OfType<DerivedEntityA>().ToList()` to filter/cast your collection to the derived type?

Comment: @daspek Thanks for your comment. CollectionA can have both entities of DerivedEntityA and B, that's why I can't use `OwnedCollection` method directly.